# Re-ordering JSX including React's Context Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, use-context

I'm wondering if there is a way of re-factoring this code so that `RepeatableAttributeSetContextProvider` does not wrap all of the JSX elements but sits above them (so opens and closes before `StyledHorizontalAttributesTable`). When I do that at present, then values like `enteredObject`: "cannot be defined".

I want to try this so that I can decouple of some of the JSX that comes along with `RepeatableAttributeSetContextProvider` (such as labels) away from the rest of my JSX (to sit on top instead of wrap) Any ideas would be great!

```
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {objects.map((enteredObject, index) => (
        <RepeatableAttributeSetContextProvider
          form={form}
          object={enteredObject}
          key={`${enteredObject.key}-${enteredObject.repeatIndex}`}
        >
          <StyledHorizontalAttributesTable className="attributeset-row">
            {enteredObject.attributeCollection.questions
              .filter(filterRepeatAttributes)
              .map((attribute) => (
                <Fragment key={attribute.key}>
                  {renderAttribute(enteredObject, attribute, formLayout)}
                </Fragment>
              ))}
            <StyledButton
              className="remove-btn"
              type="link"
              buttonStyle="LINK"
              name="delete"
              dataId={`delete-${enteredObject.key}-${index}`}
              icon="bin"
              onClick={() => onRemove(enteredObject)}
            >
              <Message id="Form.Button.Remove" defaultMessage="Remove" />
            </StyledButton>
          </StyledHorizontalAttributesTable>
        </RepeatableAttributeSetContextProvider>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {objects.map((enteredObject, index) => (
        <>
          <RepeatableAttributeSetContextProvider
            form={form}
            object={enteredObject}
            key={`${enteredObject.key}-${enteredObject.repeatIndex}`} 
          />
          <StyledHorizontalAttributesTable className="attributeset-row">
            {enteredObject.attributeCollection.questions
              .filter(filterRepeatAttributes)
              .map((attribute) => (
                <Fragment key={attribute.key}>
                  {renderAttribute(enteredObject, attribute, formLayout)}
                </Fragment>
              ))}
            <StyledButton
              className="remove-btn"
              type="link"
              buttonStyle="LINK"
              name="delete"
              dataId={`delete-${enteredObject.key}-${index}`}
              icon="bin"
              onClick={() => onRemove(enteredObject)}
            >
              <Message id="Form.Button.Remove" defaultMessage="Remove" />
            </StyledButton>
          </StyledHorizontalAttributesTable>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

But then you obviously won't have any access to the (assumed) context provided by `RepeatableAttributeSetContextProvider`. If you do need it, then you do need to wrap your JSX within it. If you don't need it, then why have the component at all?